# How to order data horizontally (column-wise)?

Tags: r, sorting, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have data in the following manner. For each category `x` taking values a, b, or c, `y` is an integer.

| x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | x3 | y3 | x4 | y4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | 7 | b | 4 | c | 4 | b | 1 |
| a | 5 | a | 9 | b | 1 | b | 7 |

I'd like to sort the data in ascending order column-wise (horizontally) when `x = "b"`. Desired output:

| x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | x3 | y3 | x4 | y4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b | 1 | b | 4 | b | 7 | c | 4 |
| b | 1 | b | 7 | a | 5 | a | 9 |

I tried using a bubble sort algorithm to arrange the `y` values, but unable to conditionally do it when `x = "b"`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Great first question! Next time, it'll make even easier if you provided a reproducible data set. For instance, you can use `dput(your_example_data)` and copy paste the output here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tidyr` + `dplyr` way:

1. `pivot_longer` to set the data in a tidy format.
2. Create a factor with ordered levels, with `"b"` as the first level and other by order of appearance.
3. Arrange the data accordingly.
4. Create a new `id` within each group to match new order.
5. Pivot back to wider format.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_pattern = "(x|y)(\\d+)", names_to = c(".value", "value")) %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = c("b", setdiff(unique(x), "b")), ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(id, x, y) %>% 
  mutate(value = data.table::rowid(id)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "value", values_from = c("x", "y"), names_sep = "", names_vary = "slowest")

#   id x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4
# 1  1  b  1  b  4  b  7  c  4
# 2  2  b  1  b  7  a  5  a  9
```

Answer (score 2):

A little awkward, but works.

```
lapply(asplit(dat, 1), matrix, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE) |>
  lapply(as.data.frame) |>
  sapply(\(x) {
    s <- split(x, x[, 1] == 'b')
    s$`TRUE` <- s$`TRUE`[order(s$`TRUE`[, 2]), ]
    r <- rbind(s$`TRUE`, s$`FALSE`)
    asplit(r, 1) |> unlist()
  }) |> t() |> as.data.frame() |> setNames(names(dat))
#   x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 x4 y4
# 1  b  1  b  4  b  7  c  4
# 2  b  1  b  7  a  5  a  9
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- yaj::read.table2('x1 y1  x2  y2  x3  y3  x4  y4
b   7   b   4   c   4   b   1
a   5   a   9   b   1   b   7')
```